# BibLaTeX - Automatic replacement of empty fields 'date', 'publisher', 'location' by "no date", "no publisher"

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I try to change the `{publisher+location+date}` command so that if one (or more) of the three fields `publisher`, `location` or `date` is empty, it can be replaced by *sine nominem*, *sine loco* and *sine anno* or their equivalent.

To do this I use the commands `\iffieldundef{}` and `\ifflistundef{}`. My problem is that `\iffieldundef{date}` does not have the expected behavior and does not detect whether the `date` field is well defined or not.

I also have a problem with final punctuation, despite `\newunit` at the end of the macro...

Do you know how to do that? Here’s where I’m stuck:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose-trad1]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@book{example,
    author      = {The Author},
    title       = {A title},
    publisher   = {Hachette},
    location    = {London},
    date        = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{,\space}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
\newunit\printtext{%
\iflistundef{publisher}%
    {\iflistundef{location}%
        {\iffieldundef{date}%
            {(s\adddot\addnbspace n\adddot\addcomma s\adddot\addnbspace l\adddot\addnbspace n\adddot\addnbspace d\adddot)}%
            {(s\adddot\addnbspace n\adddot\addnbspace n\adddot\addnbspace l\adddot)\addcomma\addspace\printfield{date} }%
        }%
        {\iffieldundef{date}%
            {(s\adddot\addnbspace n\adddot\addnbspace n\adddot\addnbspace d\adddot)\addcomma\addspace\printlist{location} }%
            {(s\adddot\addnbspace n\adddot)\addcomma\addspace\printlist{location}\addcomma\addspace\printfield{date}}%
        }%
    }%
    {\iflistundef{location}%
        {\iffieldundef{date}%
            {éd\adddot\addspace \printlist{publisher}\addcomma\addspace(s\adddot\addnbspace l\adddot\addnbspace n\adddot\addnbspace d\adddot)}%
            {éd\adddot\addspace \printlist{publisher}\addcomma\addspace(s\adddot\addnbspace l\adddot)\addcomma\addspace\printfield{date} }%
        }%
        {\iffieldundef{date}%
            {éd\adddot\addspace \printlist{publisher}\addcomma\addspace\printlist{location}\addcomma\addspace(s\adddot\addnbspace d\adddot)}%
            {éd\adddot\addspace \printlist{publisher}\addcomma\addspace\printlist{location}\addcomma\addspace\printfield{date}}%
        }%
    }%
}%
\newunit}

\begin{document}
\cite{example}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be *sine nomine*?

Comment: @Bernard Oops, of course you're absolutely right! By dint of writing only the abbreviations, we end up forgetting what they mean! `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dates are handled slightly differently from other fields in `biblatex`. Internally they consist of multiple (datepart) fields. The best way to test if there is no date at all is probably to check that there is neither a `year` nor a `endyear`. That is what I implemented below with `\ifnodate{<datetype>}` (where `<datetype>` is `url` for `urldate`, `event` for `eventdate` and empty for `date`).

I have rewritten your code a bit to let it make use of bibstrings to avoid bare text and punctuations, which are strongly discouraged. I could also bring down some of the duplication by making use of the punctuation tracker, though getting the parentheses right was *interesting* (I probably missed something).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose-trad1]{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\NewBibliographyString{nopublisher,nolocation,intropublisher}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  nopublisher    = {s\adddot\addnbspace n},
  nolocation     = {s\adddot\addnbspace l},
  intropublisher = {éd\adddot},
}

\newtoggle{bbx:pld:paren}

\DeclareListWrapperFormat{publisher}{%
  \bibstring{intropublisher}\addspace
  #1}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ifnodate}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{#1year}
    {\iffieldundef{#1endyear}}
    {\@secondoftwo}}
    
\newcommand*{\dischargepunctuation}{%
  \blx@begunit
  \blx@endunit}    
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \global\togglefalse{bbx:pld:paren}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}%
    {\setunit{\addspace\bibopenparen
              \global\toggletrue{bbx:pld:paren}}%
     \bibstring{nopublisher}}
    {\printlist{publisher}}%
  \iflistundef{location}%
    {\setunit{%
       \addcomma\space
       \iftoggle{bbx:pld:paren}
         {}
         {\bibopenparen
          \global\toggletrue{bbx:pld:paren}}}%
     \bibstring{nolocation}}
    {\setunit{%
       \iftoggle{bbx:pld:paren}
         {\bibcloseparen
          \global\togglefalse{bbx:pld:paren}}
         {}%
       \addcomma\addspace}%
     \printlist{location}}%
  \ifnodate{}
    {\setunit{%
        \addcomma\space
        \iftoggle{bbx:pld:paren}
          {}
          {\bibopenparen
           \global\toggletrue{bbx:pld:paren}}}%
     \bibstring{nodate}}
    {\setunit{%
       \iftoggle{bbx:pld:paren}
         {\bibcloseparen
          \global\togglefalse{bbx:pld:paren}}
         {}%
       \addcomma\addspace}%
     \printdate}%
  \iftoggle{bbx:pld:paren}
    {\setunit{%
       \bibcloseparen
       \global\togglefalse{bbx:pld:paren}}%
     \dischargepunctuation}
    {}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{example:pld,
    author      = {The Author},
    title       = {A title},
    publisher   = {Hachette},
    location    = {London},
    date        = {1980},
}
@book{example:pln,
    author      = {The Author},
    title       = {B title},
    publisher   = {Hachette},
    location    = {London},
    date        = {1980},
}
@book{example:pnd,
    author      = {The Author},
    title       = {C title},
    publisher   = {Hachette},
    date        = {1980},
}
@book{example:pnn,
    author      = {The Author},
    title       = {D title},
    publisher   = {Hachette},
}
@book{example:nld,
    author      = {The Author},
    title       = {E title},
    location    = {London},
    date        = {1980},
}
@book{example:nln,
    author      = {The Author},
    title       = {F title},
    location    = {London},
}
@book{example:nnd,
    author      = {The Author},
    title       = {G title},
    date        = {1980},
}
@book{example:nnn,
    author      = {The Author},
    title       = {H title},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{example:pld}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Author, The, A title, éd. Hachette, London, 1980.]

Comment: Thank you very much, yes it seemed to me that it was related to the definition of the field `date` I read the documentation, but I had to miss out on that information... `;)`